# C# - constructor - change handler object

Tags: c#, constructor

I have some example code:

```
class SomeClass{

public static List<SomeClass> AllElements = new List<SomeClass>;

public int id;

public SomeClass(int element_id){
    SomeClass foundedElements = AllElements.Find( x => x.id == element_id);
    if( foundedElements == null){
     // Do some stuff
    }
    else{
     // I found element
    // I need take this found element and set "this"
    // like...:
    //this = foundedElements;

    }
}
}
```

How can I set "this" object in the constructor to another object in the same class?

I need it to create a class where I have 1 instance of this id in the project.

I can create some static method like:

```
public static SomeClass Register(int id){
 SomeClass foundedElements = AllElements.Find( x => x.id == element_id);
    if( foundedElements == null){
     // run constructor
     // and set contructor like private member
    }
    else{
     return foundedElement;

    }
}
```

but this solution is not very good for me. I need it in the constructor.

EDIT.: 
In the constructor, I need override itself...
like:

```
this = someClassObject;
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What do you mean by *"set like this"*?

Comment: Question not clear and your code will not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the instance of a class to a new instance of itself from within itself.  As you've stated above, the way to get around this would be to use a static factory method.

One other possibility would be to create a second class that was responsible to managing this collection.

Comment: I know... 
and i create something like this before...
but I wanted something that I can replace instances in the constructor...
but it isn't possible :(
ty for all :P